# how to enable duplicate detection for a azure service bus topic which is already running

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics

How to enable duplicate detection for a topic which is already running. There is no way to change this in portal and seems disabled in service bus explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broker doesn't allow changing of this property at run-time.

`The value for the requires duplicate detection property of an existing Queue cannot be changed.`

You will have to delete your entity and re-create it.